# Is there a single hundred-sided die for 2d10 (aka d10+d10) rolls, numbered 2–20?

Tags: dice

Traditionally, 1d100 is rolled by rolling two d10s, with one of the dice used for the tens’ place and the other used for the ones’ place. But it is possible to buy a hundred-sided d100 die; they look very close to spheres, and must necessarily be rather large, but they work.

A friend of mine was wondering, has anyone done that, but with the sum of 2d10 rather than two d10s used to create a d100? That is, a hundred-sided die with all the possibilities of the total of 2d10, in the proper distribution. It would range from 2–20. There would be one side labelled 2 (representing 1 + 1) and another labelled 20 (representing 10 + 10), covering the minimum and maximum rolls. There would be two sides labelled 3 and another two labelled 19. The interest is basically the same as the usual d100: you could just read off the die rather than performing some (admittedly simple) math.

My *guess* is no, because 2d10 is used much less often than 1d100, but it’d be interesting.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you want a single die that simulates the inverted V curve of the summation of 2D10, which would require 100 sides, but give results from 2 to 20.  Correct?

Comment: I doubt there is, because there's nothing more special about 2d10 than e.g. 2d6 or 2d8 - or even 1d4+3d6 (5th level rogue's dagger sneak attack) etc.  Realistically you're always going to have to add _some_ dice together when rolling physically, and there aren't any combinations that come up frequently enough that I can imagine a market existing for those dice.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle The difference between those and this is that 100-sided dice are actually produced; it wouldn’t be a separate mold, just painting different numbers on. The same is not true of the 36-sided die you’d need for 2d6 or the 64-sided die you’d need for 2d8.

Answer (score 20):

Not quite the same thing, but I do have a somewhat novelty die that approaches your problem in a different way. It is a traditional d100 pair of d10s, only the 10s digit die is larger, hollow and transparent, and the units d10 is contained inside the 10s digit die.

I see an example of a similar design on a webstore [here](https://store.boardgamebarrister.com/double-dice-d10-in-a-d10-dice-singles/).

[image: nested d10s]

Comment: Do those work well?  I'd be concerned that the lack of internal volume would interfere with the units die being able to roll freely and produce unbiased results.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight You can shake the die in your hand before rolling it.

Comment: I actually have one of these in D20 size - the inner dice can be a bit tricky to read eaisly at first glance, but as @Stef says, shake the dice well before throwing and it seems to give a nice sample of results.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight The one I own is a good deal larger than these, but as others have said, shaking them before rolling randomises enough.